# How does using async/await differ from using Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I started using (Async & Await). Before this, I used Promise to make my process Asynchronous. Like:

```
example.firstAsyncRequest()
.then(firstResponse => {
    return example.secondAsyncRequest(firstResponse)
})
.then(secondResponse => {
    return example.thirdAsyncRequest(secondResponse)
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Now I am achieving this like:

```
  try {
    const firstResponse = await example.firstAsyncRequest();
    const secondResponse = await example.secondAsyncRequest(firstResponse);
    const thirdAsyncRequest = await example.thirdAsyncRequest(secondResponse);
    console.log(thirdAsyncRequest)
  }
  catch (error) {
    // Handle error
  }
```

In both, the code-block method executes one after another and finally throws an error if any and gets caught by `catch` block. My question is, is this only a difference of syntax? Please explain or suggest me any link to understand this better.

Thank You

Comment: *"please anyone explain or suggest me any link."* <== Would be off-topic for SO. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there only difference of syntax?

Yes. Your examples are functionally equivalent **except** that your second example is missing

```
console.log(thirdAsyncRequest);
```

...after the third `await`. (That variable really should be `result` to match the first code block, or `thirdResponse` to match the other two response variables).

`async`/`await` is syntactic sugar around promise creation and consumption. It's *really helpful* sugar, but that's all it is. `async` functions return promises. `await` expressions let you wait for a promise to settle, either getting the fulfillment value if it's fulfilled or throwing an error if it's rejected. (Since rejections are errors, you can use `try`/`catch` to handle them.) An uncaught error in an `async` function (whether a synchronous error or a promise rejection observed by `await`) causes the promise the `async` function returned to be rejected with that error. Otherwise, the function's promise is resolved to whatever the function's code returns: if it returns a non-thenable, the promise is fulfilled with that value; if it returns a thenable, the promise is fulfilled or rejected based on the settlement of that thenable.

*(Re "resolve" vs. "fulfill" and such, I've written up [this post on promise terminology](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)*

Comment: Only weird thing: you can await any expression, as it gets converted to a promise. 
`await 1` returns 1, but you can't `1.then()` (meaning that you can accidentally await a function you don't need to without ever knowing)

Comment: @CodyG.: because `await` is not `then`, it's a generator that yields once its argument is resolved.

Comment: @georg: I don't see anything about `await` being/using a generator [in the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-await).

Comment: @CodyG.: Yes, exactly like returning a non-promise from a `then` callback. But for instance, `let r = await Math.random(); console.log(r);` is roughly equivalent to `Promise.resolve(Math.random()).then(r => { console.log(r); });`. (Roughly.)

Comment: I await the day someone writes your second example on accident. :P

Comment: @CodyG.: Sorry, I don't quite follow...?

Comment: I'm just saying it's much more likely for someone new to `async/await` to write unnecessarily `await Math.random();` than your second example of someone new to promises using `Promise.resolve(Math.random()).then()`

Comment: @CodyG.: Yeah. :-)